# Creating a HTTP Server in Node.js service POST with file

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, httpclient

I would like to order sent to the POST request with a parameter in the form of a JPG file.

I use HttpClient in version 4.4.1

Part of the Java code looks like this:

```
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        File file = new File("path_to_jpg");
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:1337/uploadJPG");
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        builder.addPart("upfile", fileBody);
        HttpEntity entity = builder.build();

        post.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
        System.out.println(response.getEntity().getContent());

    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
```

next at "http://localhost:1337/uploadJPG" want to let nodeJS have a server that will process the JPG file

the idea of server code nodeJS:

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {

    if (req.method == 'POST') {

        //process file JPG

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end('processed JPG');
    }
});

port = 1337;
host = '127.0.0.1';
server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Listening at http://' + '127.0.0.1' + ':' + 1337);
```

and now my question is, How can I create such a service in NodeJS, which will have the file in jpg?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using [Express](http://expressjs.com/) or not but if you are you can use a middleware like [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) which makes it very simple to handle MultiPart data and files.

Comment: Multer requires the type 'multipart/form-data' but my .jpg files have type: 'application / octet-stream'

Besides the multer does not require that the files were already on the hard drive?
The target the server will be in a different location than the Java application